# Difference between cp and cp -rf on a Mac

Tags: bash, zsh, macos, cp

Could anybody explain is there any difference between `cp some-file.txt some-folder` and `cp -rf some-file.txt some-folder` on a Mac?

I was told that `cp -rf` forces `cp` to overwrite existing files, but it seems it overwrite them even without `-rf`.

So what is the reason to use `-rf` here then?

Comment: The macOS `cp` does not have an `-r` option. It has an `-R` option that only comes into effect when the source is a directory.

Comment: Remember that your Mac has documentation for command like `cp` built-in. See `man cp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-r` isn’t useful when copying a single file (it instructs `cp` to copy directories recursively). On top of that, on Macs (and [POSIX `cp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)) it’s `-R`, not `-r`.

`-f` forces overwrites by *deleting* the target file if necessary. Try this:

```
cp some-file.txt some-folder
chmod 000 some-folder/some-file.txt
cp some-file.txt some-folder
```

The second `cp` will fail because `some-file.txt` can’t be written. Now add `-f`:

```
cp -f some-file.txt some-folder
```

This time `cp` succeeds because, while it can’t write to the existing `some-file.txt`, it can delete it and copy the file again.

`-f` isn’t Mac-specific, it’s [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html):

> If a file descriptor for a destination file cannot be obtained, as described in step 3.a.ii., attempt to unlink the destination file and proceed.